# Less than operator in script from piped command

Tags: pipe, test, ansible

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and working with `ansible`.  I've got a test to see if somethings changed.  Essentially, if the number of lines after grepping are "less than 2".

I can retrieve the number using the following pipe construct:

```
realm list | grep active-directory | wc -l
```

How can I test if the result is less than 2?

Comment: type `man test` it should tell you what you need to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution thanks to @ctrl-alt-delor was the following:

```
test $(realm list | grep active-directory | wc -l) -lt 2 && echo true || echo false
```

`test` is a standard [POSIX utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html)

Answer (score 3):

```
if [ "$(realm list | grep -c -wF active-directory)" -lt 2 ]; then
    echo is less than 2
else
    echo is 2 or more
fi
```

`grep` can count.  Here we use that fact to count the number of lines containing the word `active-directory`.

The `-c` option to `grep` is what makes `grep` return the number of lines matching. The `-F` option disables regular expression matching, and makes `grep` instead use string comparisons.

The `-w` option is non-standard, but commonly implemented.  It forces the given pattern to be a separate word, meaning that the match must have non-word characters (or nothing) on both sides of the given string.  A non-word character is any character *outside* of the set `[[:alnum:]_]`, i.e. anything that is not an alphanumeric or underscore.  This means `active-directory3` would not match `active-directory` if `-w` is used with `grep`, neither would `inactive-directory`.

Comment: (note that with `-w`, that would still match on `hyper-active-directory-3`)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yep, but it's still a step up from not caring about it at all.

Comment: Yes, but without knowing the format of the OP's output, it's hard to tell whether `-w` is needed, useful, enough or not. `grep  -c '[[:space:]]active-directory$'` may or may not be better. If the realm type is always at the end of the line and delimited with spaces, and it's that  type only we want to match.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do

```
if realm list | awk '/active-directory/ && n++ {exit 1}'; then
  echo less than 2
else
  echo 2 or more
fi
```

We're telling `awk` to exit with a "false" exit status as soon as it finds the second line containing `active-directory`. That saves having to look for all the matches when we already have our answer by the second.